# Gulp Concat + Browserync restarting

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-concat, gulp-browser-sync

I'm using gulp concat and browserync. When I run gulp, it starts browserync and concatenates and reloads all js files found in modules. The problem is that it only does the concatenation of js files once, so I need to stop running gulp and run it again so I can see any changes reflected to js files. I only see the gulp notify task after stoping and restarting gulp too. How do I setup gulp so that always bundles and compiles the js and then runs browersync?

Here is my gulpfile

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var notify = require('gulp-notify');


// default 
gulp.task('default', ['browserSync', 'scripts'], function (){
// Reloads the browser whenever HTML or JS files change
gulp.watch('app/*.html', browserSync.reload); 
gulp.watch('app/modules/**/*.js', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
return gulp.src('app/modules/**/**.js')
  .pipe(concat('main.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('app/build/js'))
  .pipe(notify({ message: 'Scripts in modules have been bundled!' }));
});

//start browsersync
gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
browserSync.init({
server: {
  baseDir: 'app'
},
})
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
// watch 
gulp.task('watch', ['browserSync', 'scripts'], function (){
    // Reloads the browser whenever HTML or JS files change
    gulp.watch('app/*.html', browserSync.reload); 
    gulp.watch('app/modules/**/*.js', ['scripts']);
});

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
   return gulp.src('app/modules/**/**.js')
      .pipe(concat('main.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('app/build/js'))
      .pipe(notify({ message: 'Scripts in modules have been bundled!' }))
      .pipe(browserSync.reload({
          stream: true
      }));
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch', 'scripts']);
```

Comment: This works although I needed to add an additional ` ) ` after  ` stream: true ` . For some reason gulp notify doesn't work now, but it isn't crucial. The build works now without having to restart gulp, thanks!

Comment: Ah. I missed a closing parenthesis at the end of the notify pipe. Try adding that and see if that works. That should fix it.

Comment: that worked, thank you ```.pipe(notify({ message: 'Scripts in modules have been bundled!' }))
      .pipe(browserSync.reload({
          stream: true
      })); ```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but could you try to put

`gulp.watch('app/modules/**/*.js', ['scripts']);`

under task "default"

As I understand your gulp didn't watch your files and run the script

P.S. I'm not expert in gulp if it doesn't work out I'm sorry.